# Why can other methods be "static" but a constructor cannot?

Tags: java, static, constructor

I do not understand why the main method has to be static. I understand static variables but static methods are difficult for me to grasp. Do static method exists so that one can create two methods with the same name in two different classes that won't clash with each other?

Also, I don't understand why I can't create a static constructor.

Could anyone help explain this concept?

Comment: this is a sort tutorial from Oracle on statics: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @user983246 If you find an answer to a question, we appreciate a click on the Accept check-mark. You even get points for doing it!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Java has <del>[static constructors]</del> [static initialization blocks](http://www.snippetit.com/2009/03/java-static-constructor/) which can be viewed as a "static constructor":

```
class Foo {
  static String Bar;
  static {
     // "static constructor"
     Bar = "Hello world!";
  }
}
```

In any case, the only method in the main class which *must* be static is the `main` method. This is because it is invoked *without* first creating an instance of the "main class". A common technique, and the one I prefer, is to quickly *get out* of static context:

```
class Main {
   int argCount;

   // constructor
   public Main (String[] args) {
     // and back to boring ol' non-static Java
     argCount = args.length;       
   }

   void runIt () {
      System.out.println("arg count: " + argCount);
   }

   // must be static -- no Main instance created yet
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Main me = new Main(args);
      me.runIt();
   }
}
```

Also, static has nothing to do with "name clashes". A static method (or variable) is simply a method (or variable) that is *not* associated with a specific instance of a type. I would recommend reading through the [Classes and Objects Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) and the section [Understanding Instance and Class Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Happy coding.

Comment: This is not called constructor. This is actually called static initialization block that executes at class loading. To say it a constructor is wrong as constructor for a class, creates an object of that class.

Comment: @Ankit The code in this answer is not compiling. Why does the constructor have a return type - isn't that illegal ? Removing it allows for compilation.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary I do not see which constructor you are talking about. What class you are talking about.

Comment: You intended `public void Main (String[] args)` to be the constructor for the Main class, right ? It is illegal as it has the `void` return type. This code shouldn't compile. @Ankit

Comment: No, its not the constructor. Also its `main` (small case M) and not `Main` (upper case M).

Answer (score 26):

I am sharing one of the reason "why not a java constructor be static".

Simply to say, "A java constructor is always non static" because,

The purpose of the constructor is only to initialize/construct the object, and to make inheritance possible. To do these we need to use the two useful java keywords (cum non-static variables) such as this and super. 
  We will use 'this' to initialize the object.
  We/Java will use super(ofcourse super()) to invoke super class constructor so that super object(or Object class) created first then the child object(hence the inheritance)
  If the constructor is static then we cant use that two keywords(non-static variables) inside the constructor(As we know non-static stuff cant be referenced from static context)

So java constructors should not static.

Comment: Can you explain when the super constructor is invoked?

Answer (score 7):

Static methods belong to a class, not an object. The main method must be static because it is called first, before any other code has executed to instantiate any objects. It provides an entry point to the program. Static methods are called from outside of the container of an object. The same is true of static class variables. Only one copy exists for the entire class, as opposed to a member variable, which is created once for each object created from a class. They are used to store data for the class, such as the number of object instances have been created and not destroyed. This data belongs with the class. A good example of a static method is in the singleton pattern, where the constructor is private and can only be accessed by a static member function. A function outside the class would be unable to replicate this functionality. This method acts on class data and objects, so logically belongs to the same class. This all boils down to encapsulation. A class is responsible only for itself and knows only itself.

On the other hand, object methods are meant to operate on the data associated with a single instance of a class, an object. Constructors are the code that is used to initialize an object and set it's data to an initial state. They are executed immediately (and automatically) after the memory has been allocated to store a new object. Even if you do not explicitly define a constructor, a kind of "default constructor" is executed in order to map the object's member variables and the object's method code to the new object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys! The concept seems to be sinking in much better than before. You guys rock!

Comment: You mentioned what is static for a class, method etc. You never touched why a constructor can't be static?

Comment: @Siva She kinda did. Constructors are associated with an object's state. Constructors are "[...] used to initialize an object and set its data to an initial state." Static methods don't have access to instance variables. So if a constructor would be static, it could not initialize any instance variables.

Answer (score 7):

Constructor is used to create Objects.

Static is generally which is same for all objects.

So, if we have had static constructors creation of one object would affect all the other existing objects.

Static methods only reference to static variables. Therefore all the initial parameters which you are giving to create an object would change for all objects. It is no point creating similar objects for no use.

Hope this helps.... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Constructor** is the property of an object while **static** has nothing to do with object. That's why there is nothing like **static constructor**. But we have static block to do the similar task as constructor i.e. initialization of fields etc.

Answer (score 1):

On page 272 of Thinking In Java, 4th Edition, by Bruce Eckel, it says:

> ²The constructor is also a static method even though the static keyword is not explicit. So to be precise, a class is first loaded when any of its static members is accessed.

A little bit more context.

> ... the compiled code for each class exists in its own separate file. That file isn't loaded until the code is needed. In general you can say "class code is loaded at the point of first use." This is usually when the first object of that class is constructed, but loading also occurs when a static field or static method is accessed.²

This makes a lot of sense, if you think about the rule that says that a static method can't use non-static methods of the same class. I had this doubt a couple weeks ago when I couldn't understand how, using the Singleton Pattern, you could access the constructor inside the static method that is used to create a new instance of that class. Today I was flipping through the book and I came across this explanation.

It also makes sense in a way that, if the constructor wasn't static, you'd first need an instance of that class to be able to access it, but I guess this could spark up the old discussion about the chicken or the egg.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are neither entirely static (class level) or entirely non-static (instance level).

- Unlike instance methods, constructors are not inherited.
- Unlike static methods, a constructor can refer to `this`.

So, why can't you declare a constructor `static`?

Well, my take is that a (redundant) `static` keyword would be confusing and would not serve any purpose.  Therefore they decided not to allow it.

---

The explanation that static initialization blocks can be viewed as constructors is (IMO) conceptually wrong.  (It is analogous to saying that an instance initialization block is a regular constructor.  Which is equally wrong.)

The key distinctions between static initialization and construction<sup>1</sup> are:

- static initialization happens at an indeterminate time<sup>2</sup>; there is no equivalent to `new` for class initialization,
- there is no straight-forward way to pass (constructor) parameters to the initialization code
- there is no practical way to recover from errors occurring during static initialization.

<sup>1 - Hypothetically, if class initialization *was* explicit, then it would make sense to have static constructors.  But the downsize would be that applications would need to explicitly "construct" all of the classes that they used ... which would be horrible.</sup>

<sup>2 - You have a degree of control if you load a class dynamically, but even then if the class has already been loaded and initialized in the current classloader, then attempting to control initialization will fail.</sup>

---

> I do not understand why the main method has to be static.

It has to be if you want the `main` method to act as an entrypoint for your application.

The problem is that if `main` was an instance method, then there would need to be an instance of your entrypoint class to call the `main` method on.  But how do you create it?  Which constructor would you choose?  What if there was no public constructor?

The bottom line is that this is the way that Java was designed ... back in the 1990's ... and so far they have not seen the need to change this.

---

Answer (score 1):

a) static is belongs to class not object and constrictor is called during the object creation.
b) if we create a constructor as static then it can't be call by subclass as static is accessible only from class not by sub class. So during subclass object creation it can't be call the present class constructor.
c) static members are executed first in the program, so if we declare constructor as static then it will executed before object creation which is oppose the purpose of the constructor.

If we declare constructor as static then it will give compile time error.
If we want to initialize static member then need to use of static block.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple example as an answer to a related question yesterday which may help make things more understandable: [what's the point of java constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778997/whats-the-point-of-java-constructor/7779356#7779356)

The point of Static methods is that they can be called without creating an instance of a class, while "normal" instance methods are related to an instance, and can not be called without one.

Since the Main method of the Main class is the entry point of the program, no instance can possibly have been created yet, so naturally, you can not access it via an instance. Therefore, it is Static, so it can be run as the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look on this link, it will definately help you to understand:
[Why can't make a constructor static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/why-are-you-not-able-to-declare-a-class-as-static-in-java)

AND

Constructor is called at Run-time when we create Objects.
Static is same for all objects but all objects have their own state and properties.
So, if we have had static constructors creation of one object would affect all the other existing objects.
Note: static is class level while constructors related to the objects.

e.g.

```
  public class Foo
    {
       String name;
       int id;
        // define constructors
           Foo (String name, int id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

          p s v m(String[] arg)
      {
          Foo f1 = new Foo("Amit",001);
          Foo f2 = new Foo("Rahul",002);
      }
    }
```

If we create static constructor then both objects(f1 also) will contain the last updated value regarding name and id as Rahul and 002.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor cannot be static, because in an OO language, the process for creating an object is as follows:

- allocate the object
- call the constructor to initialise the newly-allocated object

Constructors are not used anywhere else (and a type-safe language should enforce this), so it follows that a constructor will always be called in a non-static context.

If a constructor were static, it would not receive a reference to the newly-allocated object, and thus would not be able to initialise it.

Thus, a constructor can always be non-static (as it is always called from a non-static context) and must always be non-static (otherwise it would be unable to perform its task).

Answer (score 0):

The `main(String[])` method has a specific prototype that is dictated by how the Java runtime environment works. When you invoke `java MyApplication` from the command line, the Java VM will look for a static `main(String[])` method contained in that class in order to execute the application. If that method is not found, then the Java VM can't run the class as an application. That's just how the language is defined. It also means that the Java VM *doesn't create an instance* of your application class in order to run it.

Now, if you want your class to be usable either as a standalone application or as an instance that's created by something else, then you can have your class implement the `Runnable` interface, and also provide a `main` method that executes the `run` method on a new instance.

```
public class MyRunnableThing implements Runnable
{
    // Define whatever variables your runnable thing needs here as
    // private instance fields.

    /** Fulfills requirements of Runnable interface. */
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println( "I'm running..." ) ;
    }

    /** Also makes the class runnable from the console. */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        MyRunnableThing runMeNow = new MyRunnableThing() ;
        runMeNow.run() ;
    }
}
```

Now *any* class could potentially create an instance of `MyRunnableThing` and use its `run()` method to produce *the same behavior* that would have been seen by executing `java MyRunnablething`.

See also: [Working with Static Constructor in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228242/working-with-static-constructor-in-java). Some highlights from that Q&A:

- A constructor is used to create an instance of the class, so it's an instance method, not a static method.
- You can create a static method that creates an instance of the class, using the constructor. This is how the trendy new "builder" classes work.
- You can create a static method that returns a persistent, unique **singleton** instance.
- If your class has static members, then you can create a **static initializer** to initialize the values of those members.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Constructor is to Construct an Object i.e. to initialize class's instance variables either their default values or by their initialized values. non-static Instance variables can't be accessed by static methods . So constructor is not static.

Answer (score 0):

The method declared as static requires no object creation .As we don't create object for the main method it is declared as static.

constructor is implicitly called to initialize an object, so there is no purpose in having a static constructor.

Comment: That is just not what the static method means. Static methods are there to initialise static instance variables. Static variable or method are there for automatically called and much more. You don't create object for methods but for class. Beside that constructors are special type of methods which means not all the rules apply exactly same as other methods.

Comment: Yes , you are correct .We create objects for Class but for calling a method in the class we have to use that object .

Answer (score 0):

**First**, the key word static means that everything marked static must be the class-level thing and belongs to the class only.While constructors belong to object and they may usually be called when we use the **new** operator.So we now know that a constructor is not even a class property,how could we possibly mark it as static?

**Second**,static constructor violates the whole purpose of inheritance in java.Every time just before we create an subclass object ,JVM automatically calls the superclass constructor to make it ready for the subclass object to be created.But if we mark the constructor static,the subclass will not be able to access the constructor of its superclass because it's marked static thus belongs to class only.

Answer (score -1):

Java does not permit to declare a constructor as static. Following are the reasons.

1. Static means for the same class. i.e, static methods cannot be inherited.
2. With static, "this" reference (keyword) cannot be used. "this" is always linked to an object. A constructor always belongs to some object.
3. If a constructor is static, an object of subclass cannot access. If static is allowed with constructor, it is accessible within the class but not by subclass.

Answer (score -1):

Static Belongs to Class, Constructor to Object

We know that static methods, block or variables belong to the class. Whereas a Constructor belongs to the object and called when we use the new operator to create an instance. Since a constructor is not class property, it makes sense that it’s not allowed to be static.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22266669)