# Class constructor or static object-returning method?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

Curiousity made me ask this question. I'd like to know what is better to use to instantiate a class.

I could either do this with a constructor:

```
public ExampleClass(someParameters){}
```

, or I could do this with a public static method:

```
public static ExampleClass getInstance(someParameters){return new ExampleClass}
```

Personally I do like to use static methods to instantiate a class because it looks cleaner to instantiate a class that way. However, I would really appreciate some supported opinions on this because I'm just a hobbyist that would like to code more professionally-looking.

Comment: Please note that your second example won't compile.  It needs a return type and method name.

Comment: With the static method, you have the option of returning an existing object, or an object of a subtype. That's why factory methods are a very common pattern.

Comment: *"because it looks cleaner"* - _whaaat_? You like to not see the `new` keyword when instantiating classes?

Comment: It will compile because I return a object of ExampleClass..

Comment: It looks like you have seen a Singleton design pattern implementation. Why exactly do you want to have the ctor to be static? Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780406/why-can-other-methods-be-static-but-a-constructor-cannot and compare with your question

Comment: Please see my edit! I forgot to specify the name of the static method, sorry for that!

And why did this get downvoted? I'd like other people to see this post because it's something that I couldn't find somewhere else.

Comment: See [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for an example of a class that uses factory methods effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so your question is should you use static factory methods? Well use them when they are appropriate. For example they can have a name like `of` or `create`, etc. So they can be *named* (unlike constructors that must have the same name as the class).

Then you can return a subtype, or cache an object - you can't do that with a plain constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From the Effective Java book, Joshua Block contests that it is better to have static factory methods for object creation than plain old constructors.  Advantages include

1. Unlike constructors, they have names
2. Unlike constructors, they do not require to create a new object each time they’re invoked
3. Unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their 
   return type
4. They reduce verbosity of creating parameterized type instances

Disadvantages:

1. They cannot be used in subclasses construction
2. They are not readily distinguishable from other static methods

Comment: I don't know why I'm seeing this a year later, but thanks for your answer, it really helps.