# what is the role of constructor while creating an object in java

Tags: default, default-constructor

> class class_name = new class();

this is how we define and instantiate objects in java.

My question is: What is the role played here by the constructor 'class()' here in this statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the point of java constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778997/whats-the-point-of-java-constructor)

Comment: There are plenty of this kind of question. Search first before asking.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor provides the chance to have some code run as the new object is instantiated.

Common uses for constructors are to set default properties, to establish an environment within which the object can operate (gathering resources etc...), registering Event Handlers (Listeners for the Java minded...)

Answer (score 1):

Constructor is used to initialize member variables of a class and prepare object for use. If you don't define your own, Java will generate default constructor, initializing member variables to default values (e.g 0 for int, null for object references). Java Object can have multiple constructors with different parameters. Constructors are similar to methods, but have no return type and their name must match name of the class.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Java